# Access-Control-Allow-Origin with CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, jsonp, cors

I started a web application project which shows data from a http server. If I run the webServer.js (implemented with installed node/express), the index.html will be executed. Because the server (where the data come from) has another domain, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load *"http-link to Server"*. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As I understand, there are only two solutions:

1. Load the web application project files to the server: same domain,
   same origin.
2. Solve the problem with the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource
       Sharing) approach.

I can't continue with solution 1. Therefore, I have to implement the second solution with CORS. Could anyone explain me what, how and where (webServer.js or index.html) I have to implement? I did check the internet, but I don't understand it. What additional libraries should I use? Keywords are angular.js or jsonp...

Thanks for your help! Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

In couple of words, you should add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to response headers on your server. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) [is](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) additional info.

Also you might wish setting

```
app.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
})
```

to prevent angular from sending [cors preflight request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests).

Comment: Why would you suggest a default content-type of multipart/form-data?  You don't know what kind of requests the OP is sending at all.  Also, this will not prevent the browser from preflighting any cross-origin requests.  There are many other factors in play that are used to determine if a preflight is required or not.